# FactoryGirl parent class factory randomly selecting one of its STI subclasses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have an `Animal` parent class.
`Bird` and `Monkey` are subclasses that extend `Animal` through STI.

```
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Bird < Animal
end

class Monkey < Animal
end
```

Is there a way to define my FactoryGirl factories so that `FactoryGirl.create(:animal)` will randomly call either `FactoryGirl.create(:bird)` or `FactoryGirl.create(:monkey)` for me?

Answer (score 2):

See https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#custom-construction. You can do:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :animal do
    initialize_with do
      if [true, false].sample
        Monkey.new
      else
        Bird.new
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a matter of preference, but I thought I'd share this alternative for future googlers:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory(:animal) do
    type { %w[Monkey Bird].sample }

    initialize_with do
      record = new(attributes)
      record.becomes(record.type.constantize)
    end
  end
end
```